# jQuery dropdown menu opens all sub-menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a problem regarding jQuery. I want to make a responsive drop-down menu with sub-menus. If the window width is less than 700px the submenus will trigger onClick. If the window is wider than 700px the submenus will triger onHover.

The window.resize code is there to make the change when I resize the window, without refreshing the page. It works, but the problem is that if I click/hover any of the two links with nested sub-list it opens ALL the nested lists. Other than that works as it should.

This is the Html code (the .navLevel2 class has display: none):

```
    <div class="mainNav">
     <ul class="navLevel1">
    <li><a href="">link 1</a></li>
        <li class="fakeLink">link 2
           <ul class="navLevel2">
            <li><a href="">link 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">link 2.2</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="fakeLink">link 3
           <ul class="navLevel2">
            <li><a href="">link 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">link 3.2</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        function checkWidth() {
            var windowsize = $(window).width();
            if (windowsize < 700) {
                $('.navLevel1').addClass('small');
                $('.fakeLink').attr('onclick','return click_m()');
            } else {
                $('.navLevel1').addClass('big');
                $('.fakeLink').attr('onmouseover','return toggle_m()').attr('onmouseout','return toggle_m()');
            }
        }
        checkWidth();  // Execute on load

        $(window).resize(function() {
            if($(window).width() < 700) {
                $('.mainNav > ul').removeClass('big');
                $('.mainNav > ul').addClass('small');
                $('.fakeLink').attr('onclick','return click_m()');
                $('.fakeLink').removeAttr('onmouseover','return toggle_m()').removeAttr('onmouseout','return toggle_m()');
            }
            else if($(window).width() > 700) {
                $('.mainNav > ul').removeClass('small');
                $('.mainNav > ul').addClass('big');
                $('.fakeLink').attr('onmouseover','return toggle_m()').attr('onmouseout','return toggle_m()');
                $('.fakeLink').removeAttr('onclick','return click_m()');    
            }
        }) // window.resize
      }) // document.ready
    </script>
```

The trigers, written in header:

```
function click_m(){
  $('.fakeLink > ul').slideToggle(300); 
}

function toggle_m(){
  $('.fakeLink > ul').stop().slideToggle(300);  
}
```

So, the problem is:
If I hover/click on Link 2, it opens ALL the nested lists. Same if click/hover the Link 3.
Where is the problem, because I can't find the bug.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change your click_m function to target the specific element that's being clicked. I tried this:

```
function click_m($target){
  $($target).children().slideToggle(300); 
}
```

and had the script call:

```
$('.fakeLink').attr('onclick','return click_m(this)');
```

which seems to work. You can see it here: [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/rwaymouth/pen/yHGkt)

You'd then just duplicate the concept with the hover versions.

Answer (score 0):

The selector `.fakeLink > ul` in your trigger -

```
function click_m(){
   $('.fakeLink > ul').slideToggle(300);   
}

function toggle_m(){
   $('.fakeLink > ul').stop().slideToggle(300);  
}
```

will try to find all `<ul>` under the class `.fakeLink`, and thus all of them show.

You can use `next()` to just select the very next `<ul>` and I believe that should work.  So -

```
function click_m(){
   $('.fakeLink').next('ul').slideToggle(300);   
}

function toggle_m(){
   $('.fakeLink').next('ul').stop().slideToggle(300);  
}
```

Not tested.

Comment: Sorry, but with next() doesn't do anything, regardless of window size. But thanks anyway!